# Pytest with line-delineated json

Tags: python, json, pytest, tweets

I'm relatively new to Python and really new to `pytest`. Anyways, I'm trying to write some tests for parsing tweets that are in line-delineated json. Here's a simplified example `test_cases.jsonl`:

```
{"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"created_at":"Sat Aug 20 01:00:12 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[{"indices":[97,116],"text":"StandWithLouisiana"}]}}
{"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"created_at":"Sat Aug 20 01:01:35 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[]}}
```

What I would like to do is test a function like the following:

```
def hashtags(t):
    return ' '.join([h['text'] for h in t['entities']['hashtags']])
```

I can test a single line of the JSON as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture
def tweet(file='test_cases.jsonl'):
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            return json.loads(line)


def test_hashtag(tweet):
    assert hashtags(tweet) == 'StandWithLouisiana'
```

(I'm just giving the file name as the argument for the function for this example)

This works in the sense that the test passes because the first line passes the test, but what I'm basically trying to do is something like this and I don't expect this to work as it is written.

```
def test_hashtag(tweet):
    assert hashtags(tweet) == 'StandWithLouisiana' # first tweet
    assert hashtags(tweet) == ''    # second tweet
```

This fails because it tests whether the first tweet (line in the json) is empty, not the second. I assume that's because of the `return` in the fixture, but if I try to `yield` instead of `return`, I get a `yield_fixture function has more than one 'yield'` error` (and the second line still fails).

What I'm doing now to get around this issue is to make each line a separate JSON file and then creating a separate fixture for each of them. 
(For shorter examples, I'm using `StringIO` to write the JSON inline). 
This does work but feels inelegant. I have a feeling that I should use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` for this, but I can't get my head around it. I think I also tried `pytest_generate_tests` to do this as well, but it would up testing every key.  Is it possible to do what I'm thinking of, or is it better to create separate fixtures when I have different values for the assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most fitting approach for you would be parametrizing the fixture:

```
import json
import pathlib
import pytest


lines = pathlib.Path('data.json').read_text().split('\n')

@pytest.fixture(params=lines)
def tweet(request):
    line = request.param
    return json.loads(line)


def hashtags(t):
    return ' '.join([h['text'] for h in t['entities']['hashtags']])


def test_hashtag(tweet):
    assert hashtags(tweet) == 'StandWithLouisiana'
```

This will invoke `test_hashtag` once with each returned value of `tweet`:

```
$ pytest -v
...
test_spam.py::test_hashtag[{"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"created_at":"Sat Aug 20 01:00:12 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[{"indices":[97,116],"text":"StandWithLouisiana"}]}}]
test_spam.py::test_hashtag[{"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"created_at":"Sat Aug 20 01:01:35 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[]}}]
...
```

#### Edit: extending the fixture to provide the expected value

You can include the expected value into `tweet` fixture parameters, which are then passed through to the test unchanged. In the below example, the expected tags are zipped with the file lines to build pairs of the form `(line, tag)`. The `tweet` fixture loads the line into a dictionary, passing the tag through, so the `tweet` argument in the test becomes a pair of values.

```
import json
import pathlib
import pytest


lines = pathlib.Path('data.json').read_text().split('\n')
expected_tags = ['StandWithLouisiana', '']

@pytest.fixture(params=zip(lines, expected_tags),
                ids=tuple(repr(tag) for tag in expected_tags))
def tweet(request):
    line, tag = request.param
    return (json.loads(line), tag)


def hashtags(t):
    return ' '.join([h['text'] for h in t['entities']['hashtags']])


def test_hashtag(tweet):
    data, tag = tweet
    assert hashtags(data) == tag
```

The test run yields two tests as before:

```
test_spam.py::test_hashtag['StandWithLouisiana'] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_hashtag[''] PASSED
```

#### Edit 2: using indirect parametrization

Another and probably a more clean approach would be to let the `tweet` fixture only handle the parsing the tweet from the raw string, moving the parametrization to the test itself. I'm using the [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) to pass the raw line to the `tweet` fixture here:

```
import json
import pathlib
import pytest


lines = pathlib.Path('data.json').read_text().split('\n')
expected_tags = ['StandWithLouisiana', '']

@pytest.fixture
def tweet(request):
    line = request.param
    return json.loads(line)


def hashtags(t):
    return ' '.join([h['text'] for h in t['entities']['hashtags']])


@pytest.mark.parametrize('tweet, tag', 
                         zip(lines, expected_tags),
                         ids=tuple(repr(tag) for tag in expected_tags),
                         indirect=('tweet',))
def test_hashtag(tweet, tag):
    assert hashtags(tweet) == tag
```

The test run now also yields two tests:

```
test_spam.py::test_hashtag['StandWithLouisiana'] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_hashtag[''] PASSED
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This isn't exactly what I want, however. I'm not so much testing the json as I'm testing the function. Unless I did something wrong with what you have here, you are testing whether every tweet has the text `StandWithLouisiana`.  However, I expect the second tweet to return an empty string, and I want to make sure that my function allows for an empty string in addition to returning a value when it is present.  So basically, I have two tests, one which is `test_hashtags`, the other `test_empty_hashtag`, which I'm trying to do without creating two separate fixtures.

Comment: I think I see what you mean - can you revisit the updated answer?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'll have to try it with the real data, but this really gives me a good idea about what to do. I'm going to mark as the correct answer, but I think you need to change `tags` to `expected_tags`  for it to work.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Please revisit the answer once again - I have added another approach which you may find to be better than burdening the fixture with parameters it doesn't process.